# Android String Array

Tags: android, arrays, string

Hello all i have the code below which produces four wheels each with the numbers 0-9. I think these numbers are being called for each wheel in the section of code after:

```
/**
* Initializes wheel
* @param id the wheel widget Id
*/
```

Is there a way i can change this so i can set certain WORDS instead of NUMBERS for each one of the four wheels like and array or string.

So i would have four arrays (strings) with different words for each wheel.

Thanks in advance.

```
public class PasswActivity extends Activity {
@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

    setContentView(R.layout.passw_layout);
    initWheel(R.id.passw_1);
    initWheel(R.id.passw_2);
    initWheel(R.id.passw_3);
    initWheel(R.id.passw_4);

    Button mix = (Button)findViewById(R.id.btn_mix);
    mix.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
        public void onClick(View v) {
            mixWheel(R.id.passw_1);
            mixWheel(R.id.passw_2);
            mixWheel(R.id.passw_3);
            mixWheel(R.id.passw_4);
        }
    });


}

// Wheel scrolled flag
private boolean wheelScrolled = false;

// Wheel scrolled listener
OnWheelScrollListener scrolledListener = new OnWheelScrollListener() {
    public void onScrollingStarted(WheelView wheel) {
        wheelScrolled = true;
    }
    public void onScrollingFinished(WheelView wheel) {
        wheelScrolled = false;

    }
};

// Wheel changed listener
private OnWheelChangedListener changedListener = new OnWheelChangedListener() {
    public void onChanged(WheelView wheel, int oldValue, int newValue) {
        if (!wheelScrolled) {

        }
    }
};




/**
 * Initializes wheel
 * @param id the wheel widget Id
 */
private void initWheel(int id) {
    WheelView wheel = getWheel(id);
    wheel.setViewAdapter(new NumericWheelAdapter(this, 0, 9));
    wheel.setCurrentItem((int)(Math.random() * 10));

    wheel.addChangingListener(changedListener);
    wheel.addScrollingListener(scrolledListener);
    wheel.setCyclic(true);
    wheel.setInterpolator(new AnticipateOvershootInterpolator());
}

/**
 * Returns wheel by Id
 * @param id the wheel Id
 * @return the wheel with passed Id
 */
private WheelView getWheel(int id) {
    return (WheelView) findViewById(id);
}

/**
 * Tests entered PIN
 * @param v1
 * @param v2
 * @param v3
 * @param v4
 * @return true 
 */
private boolean testPin(int v1, int v2, int v3, int v4) {
    return testWheelValue(R.id.passw_1, v1) && testWheelValue(R.id.passw_2, v2) &&
        testWheelValue(R.id.passw_3, v3) && testWheelValue(R.id.passw_4, v4);
}

/**
 * Tests wheel value
 * @param id the wheel Id
 * @param value the value to test
 * @return true if wheel value is equal to passed value
 */
private boolean testWheelValue(int id, int value) {
    return getWheel(id).getCurrentItem() == value;
}

/**
 * Mixes wheel
 * @param id the wheel id
 */
private void mixWheel(int id) {
    WheelView wheel = getWheel(id);
    wheel.scroll(-25 + (int)(Math.random() * 50), 2000);
}
```

}

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just use an `ArrayWheelAdapter<T>` instead of the `NumericWheelAdapter`.

If you look closely at your own code, you will find a line where your adapter is created

```
new NumericWheelAdapter(this, 0, 9)
```

An adaptor is something the wheel UI can hook onto and grab data to display. This will create an adapter containing the numbers zero through nine. To create an adapter that displays the words "Abc", "Foo", and "Bar" use this.

```
new ArrayWheelAdapter<String>(this, new String[]{"Abc", "Foo", "Bar"})
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer but i dont really understand how to implement that to make four different arrays. COuld you help me out a little more? Do i have to add the four different arrays into the ArrayWheelAdapter file and if so how would i get them into this java file. Thanks.

Comment: Sorry to be a pain but i am quite new to android development could you expand on your answer maybe show me a little code?

Comment: @Matt I added an example on how to do this. Hope it helps!

Comment: Hi vidstige thanks for the code but when i change the line to the new code you posted i am getting a few errors:  "The method setViewAdapter(WheelViewAdapter) in the type WheelView is not applicable for the arguments (ArrayAdapter<String>)" and "The constructor ArrayAdapter<String>(String[]) is undefined"

Comment: @Matt ops, of course I meant to say ArrayWheelAdapter. Do you know how to browse the class hierarchy and look at other subclasses yourself?

Comment: Sorry no, i am pretty new to android, just like to say thanks for all your help so far i added the new code and the error is "The constructor ArrayWheelAdapter<String>(String[]) is undefined" Think i have to add something into that file you can view the code here if it helps http://code.google.com/p/android-wheel/source/browse/trunk/wheel/src/kankan/wheel/widget/adapters/ArrayWheelAdapter.java

Comment: look at the import statements in your file that you have right now. Do you see anything about the NumericWheelAdapter you where using before? Do you have any guess on how resolve this problem?

Comment: I have this import kankan.wheel.widget.adapters.ArrayWheelAdapter; but i dont have any idea really i can see how you are pulling the array in but it is just giving me an error if i put new ArrayWheelAdapter<String>(null, new String[]{"Abc", "Foo", "Bar"} it stops the error but the app just force closes

Comment: What is the exact error you got then? Can you connect your error message with the null-parameter you pass into the constructor? If you look closely at your own code you see that you actually pass {this} as the first parameter called "context".

Comment: This is the error i get if i chnage the code to the one you posted "The constructor ArrayWheelAdapter<String>(String[]) is undefined" and i am not sure what you mean by connecting with the null-parameter.

Comment: Alright. Look at the definition for {NumericalWheelAdapter}. What parameters does the constructor take? Look at your code that is already working. What are you passing to the constructor. Then look at the definition of the {ArrayWheelAdapter}. Can you see any similarities? Can you now figure out how to call the constructor yourself?

Comment: Is it anything to do with it using int so it is supposed to be numbers?

Comment: Sorry i am pretty new so cant really figure it out the NumericalWheelAdapter code is here http://code.google.com/p/android-wheel/source/browse/trunk/wheel/src/kankan/wheel/widget/adapters/NumericWheelAdapter.java and the ArrayWheelAdapter here http://code.google.com/p/android-wheel/source/browse/trunk/wheel/src/kankan/wheel/widget/adapters/ArrayWheelAdapter.java is it possible for you to take a look? Thanks so much

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/5131/discussion-between-matt-and-vidstige)